# Sum over two independent variables

Tags: list-manipulation, summation, mapthread

I have a function `f[x,y]` and try to generate a sum of it where `x` and `y` vary predictably but independently, e.g.

```
f[0,-2] + f[1,-4] + f[2,-6] + f[3,-8] + f[4,-10]
```

`Sum[f[x, y], {x, 0, 4}, {y, -2, -10, -2}]` does not work for obvious reason. I can use a third variable to generate `x` and `y`, but think that Mathematica must have an easier way.

This seems like too simple a question to ask, but I cannot find any clue in the `Sum` documentation. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `Sum[f[i, -2 (i + 1)], {i, 0, 4}]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Mathematica 13,we can just use `sum`

```
pts = {{0, -2}, {1, -4}, {2, -6}, {3, -8}, {4, -10}};
Sum[f @@ p, {p, pts}]
```

> `f[0, -2] + f[1, -4] + f[2, -6] + f[3, -8] + f[4, -10]`

Comment: Seems also work in the other versions.

Comment: Most succinct. I suppose it works as far back as the `@@` operator was defined.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps

```
Total@MapThread[F[#1, #2] &, {Range[0, 4], Range[-2, -10, -2]}]
(*F[0, -2] + F[1, -4] + F[2, -6] + F[3, -8] + F[4, -10]*)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can modify the ranges as needed.

```
Clear[alist, blist, clist, f]
alist = Range[0, 4]
blist = Range[-2, -10, -2]
clist = Transpose[{alist, blist}]
Total[f @@@ clist]
```

---

**EDIT**

Another solution could be:

```
Total@Thread[f[alist, blist]]
```

---

> f[0, -2] + f[1, -4] + f[2, -6] + f[3, -8] + f[4, -10]

Answer (score 6):

```
Inner[f, 0 ~ # ~ 4, -2 # @ 5]& @ Range
```

> ```
> f[0, -2] + f[1, -4] + f[2, -6] + f[3, -8] + f[4, -10]
> ```

```
Sum[f[i - 1, -2 i], {i, 5}]
```

> ```
> f[0, -2] + f[1, -4] + f[2, -6] + f[3, -8] + f[4, -10]
> ```

```
Tr @ Array[f[# - 1, -2 #] &, 5]
```

> ```
> f[0, -2] + f[1, -4] + f[2, -6] + f[3, -8] + f[4, -10]
> ```

```
h = Tr @* Thread @* f;
h[# - 1, -2 #] & @ Range @ 5
```

> ```
> f[0, -2] + f[1, -4] + f[2, -6] + f[3, -8] + f[4, -10]
> ```